# Re-load jqgrid data based on the asp combobox selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

Is it possible to reload jqgrid onchange of asp combobox?

EDIT :

Am trying to get dropdown list change like this :

```
  $("#txtGroupLevel").change($("#table").jqGrid({ 
         .....
  postData: { groupId: $("#txtGroupLevel option:selected").val() },
  .....
```

Is this the right way to do? even though am unable to get the selected value from dropdown.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using below, I dont know if its right way but it works:

```
 $(function () {

        $("#txtGroupLevel").change($("#table").trigger("reloadGrid"));

    });
........
.........
postData: { groupId: $("#<%= txtGroupLevel.ClientID %>").val() }
```